# Filtering ListBox results

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to make a filter listbox which works for filtering the results however the index of the selected item is still the same as the original listing order, below is how I performed filtering

```
 private void FilterTextBox_ChangedEvent(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!FilterNameTextBox.Text.Equals("Filter name....") || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            Users.ItemsSource = UserListArray
                .Where(w => w.name.ToLower().Contains(FilterNameTextBox.Text.ToLower()));

        }
    }
```

The `UserListArray.name` is what I use to match against the user input from `FilterNameTextBox.Text.ToLower()`. 
Example of my problem

**Original List**

```
AB => 1
BB => 2
CD => 3
DD => 4
```

**Filtered List** by letter D

```
CD => 1
DD => 2
```

AS you see the object being returned does not match what the list is reflecting,
how could I do filtering but use the new objects from the filtered list?

Comment: Yes it does it's the index in your filtered list. Something like OriginalList.IndexOf(FilteredList[0]) ?

Comment: `UserListArray[Users.SelectedIndex];` this is how I get the objects from the selecteditem right here.

Comment: You want to keep the selection after filtering?

Comment: I want to get the real object that is associated by by the selection after the original list has been filtered.

Comment: Wait a minute, your filtered does not contain new objects, it contains  references to the objects in the list you are filtering. Add the code that's failing.

Comment: OriginalList[3] == FilteredList[1]. Exact same object so OriginalList.IndexOf(FilteredList[1]) is 3

Comment: I see there is a bit of confusion but I think you get the situation now based on your last comment, I have a on selection changed event on the listbox that prints the value of selected row which was giving improper object refrences.